# How does angluar get csrf token from spring security?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have written a login screen in angular. I want to be able to login to my spring boot service. I won't be able to log in without a csrf token.
Should I make a needless call to the spring boot service just to get a csrf token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csrf` token is not required for login api. You have to exclude it in your login API.

Once the login is successfull then you've to send the token in the response so that your `Angular` application will save this token in the cookies.

From the next api, client application has to send this `csrf` token in the token to make sure there is proper authentication.

After writing the `csrf` token in the cookies of the `angular` application, you can extract token in the foolowing way.

Import HttpClientXsrfModule into your app.module.ts

```
<!-- app.module.ts -->
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports:[...,HttpClientXsrfModule,...]
```

Inject `HttpXsrfTokenExtractor` into your service or `HttpInterceptor` or file in which you want to use cookie.

```
constructor(private cookieExtractor:HttpXsrfTokenExtractor){}
```

To get the cookie, for example xsrf token

```
const xsrf: string = this.cookieExtractor.getToken();
```

Add the token in the headers

```
 if (xsrf) {
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('x-xsrf-token', xsrf) });
    }
```